# How JS reads if statements and looping through array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

The following code is a function that will loop through an array and checks to see if an array of integers is sorted, returning true  if it is, false otherwise. A friend of mine helped me out but I forget what his explanation was. For the if statement I'm having trouble understanding what its saying. Is it, if every index of the array (array[i]) is greater than every index of the array plus 1 (array[i+1]) then the variable tell is false. So for example, if the array [31, 4, 99, 23, 8] is greater than [31+1, 4+1, 99+1, 23+1, 8+1] return false? The confusion mainly comes from what exactly is "array[i+1]". Thank you in advance.

```
function isSorted(arr) {
    var tell = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            tell = false;
        }
    }
    return tell
}
```

Comment: `if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {` ==> _If element at position `i` in array is greater than the element at position `i + 1` i.e. next element_. Optimized Code:  `function isSorted(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}`

Comment: Your confusion comes from not understanding array notation. [i+1] does not mean the value +1, it means the object after the object at i. See my explanation in the answers below :D

Answer (score 1):

`arr[i]` is the current element of the array in your iteration. `arr[i + 1]` is the next element.

What your `if` statement is saying is "if the current element is greater than the next one, set `tell` to false" (because this means that the array is not sorted).

There is an off-by-one bug in this code because it looks at an element beyond the end of the array. The correct implementation would be:

```
function isSorted(arr) {
    var tell = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { // <-- loop up to the second-to-last element
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            tell = false;
        }
    }
    return tell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arr[x] means the object in the array at position 'x'

So if your array is [z, x, d, r] then the object at position 0 is "z", the object at position 1 is "x", the object at position 2 is "d", and object at position 3 is "r". So arr[0] is "z", arr[2] is "d", etc.

Your code is checking if any object at position `i` is greater than the next object in the array (aka the object at position `i+1`)

Comment: alright, so if it was instead written as `arr[i] < arr[i-1]` that would mean if any object at position i is less than the object before in the array?

Answer (score 0):

It says:

1. Set the `tell` flag to true, so unless we find a reason that the array is not sorted, we'll return true as the answer.
2. Now, for each element `arr[i]` and its next element `arr[i+1]`, do the following check: if the first is greater than the next, that means that we have a situation like `[..., 3, 2,...]`, so we know that the array is not sorted. To indicate that, we set the `tell` flag to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The +1 doesn't mean the Value + 1 but the next element. So in the first loop i is 0. Then the if checks, if the value of the element at the position 0 is greater than the value of the element 1 (0 + 1), it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i]` is the element at index `i`. `arr[i + 1]` is the element at index `i + 1`. It's the *next element*.

The *if* checks whether the current element is bigger than the next element. If every element is bigger than the next element, then that means the array is sorted in descending order. If your array is `[8, 6, 5, 1]`, then `8 > 6 > 5 > 1`. If your array was `[8, 9, 5, 1]`, then it wouldn't be ordered, since `8 < 9 > 5 > 1`.